# Counting no. of clock cycles

Tags: digital-logic, timing-analysis, propagation, sequential-logic

This question was asked in GATE 2021. Here I am finding it difficult to "manage" propagation delay of XOR gate. Solving it using timing diagram takes a lot of time and rough space.

Is there any other easier method to solve this question ? The answer is 5. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no magic here. I think the timing diagram is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Since all transitions seem to be multiples of `1ns`, you can probably avoid drawing the lines in the diagram and just write down the results as numbers in a table with each row representing one `1ns` time gap and columns representing `clk`, `Qx` etc. You will save some space and time taken to draw the line; not much benefit.

Comment: Thank you very much.